How to update an existing SQLite database in a Blazor Hybrid app with MAUI when modifying the DbContext?
What are the details of your problem?
I'm developing a Blazor Hybrid app using MAUI and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite for database management. The issue I'm facing is that when I update my DbContext by adding new tables or modifying existing ones, these changes don't automatically reflect in the SQLite database if it was already created with an earlier version of the app. This results in errors when I try to interact with the newly added or modified tables.
For example, if the app was previously installed and the database was created, and I then add a new table in the DbContext, I get an error because the database doesn't recognize the new table. I want to know how I can update the existing database on the device to match the latest version of my DbContext whenever the app is updated.
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I’ve tried the following commands:
Database.EnsureDeleted();
Database.EnsureCreated();
Database.Migrate();

Using EnsureDeleted() does solve the issue by recreating the database, but it also deletes all user data, which isn't acceptable. The other two commands (EnsureCreated() and Migrate()) don't seem to update the database schema to reflect the new tables or modifications.
My expectation is that the database should automatically update to match the changes in my DbContext without losing any existing data.
public class BitacoraContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AreaTarea> AreasTareas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SucursalTab> SucursalTabs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Revision> Revisiones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RevisionTarea> RevisionesTareas { get; set; }

    public BitacoraContext(DbContextOptions<BitacoraContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
        //Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=databse.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SucursalTab>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("SucursalesTabs");
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasMany(a => a.Areas).WithOne(t => t.SucursalTab)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TabId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Area>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Areas");
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasMany(a => a.AreasTareas).WithOne(t => t.Area)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.AreaId);

            entity.HasOne(a => a.SucursalTab).WithMany(t => t.Areas)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TabId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AreaTarea>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("AreasTareas");
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasOne(a => a.Area).WithMany(t => t.AreasTareas)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.AreaId);

            entity.HasMany(a => a.RevisionesTareas).WithOne(t => t.AreaTarea)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TareaId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Revision>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Revisiones");
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasMany(a => a.RevisionesTareas).WithOne(t => t.Revision)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.RevisionId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RevisionTarea>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("RevisionesTareas");
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasOne(a => a.Revision).WithMany(t => t.RevisionesTareas)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.RevisionId);

            entity.HasOne(a => a.AreaTarea).WithMany(t => t.RevisionesTareas)
               .HasForeignKey(t => t.TareaId);
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

using BAL;
using DAL;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Bitacora
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<BitacoraContext>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ServiceTareas>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ServiceRevisiones>();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            var app = builder.Build();

            return app;
        }
    }
}


Was the original database created using Code First with an EnsureCreated/Migrate? If not, you need to do an initial migration using "Add-Migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges". The crux of this operation will be to create the Migration History table which is what EF migrations will used to assess whether new migration scripts are reasonably safe to run. You can check your existing database for the _EFMigrationHistory table. If that table does not exist the above should create it.

In earlier versions, how did you create the database?
